# Keep jQuery modal open on C# button click

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a modal on a page that was suposed to remain open when I click a link on a ASP.NET GridView row. The click of this link fires the click of another button that calls a function on server-side. My idea was to keep my modal open, so I could fill it with what I need, using code behind. The problem is that after the modal is opened and the button is fired, the modal closes (if I remove the button click, everything works fine). I would like to know if it's possible to make it remain open. Here's what I have:

The function that open the modal and fire the button:

```
function showDetails()
{
    $("#modalDetails").dialog("open");

    var btnEmbedDetails = document.getElementById('<%=btnEmbedDetails.ClientID %>');
    btnShowDetails.click();
}
```

The link inside the GridView row:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="Details">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href='javascript:showDetails();'>Open it</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The button that calls the function on code behind:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEmbedDetails" runat="server" OnClick="EmbedDetails" style="display:none;" />
```

The function on code behind:

```
public void EmbedDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ok = "ok";
}
```

Comment: I take it that the page refreshes after the button click. If you fire an ajax call to the server the page won't refresh and the modal will remain open.

Comment: Will try it...thanks!